# Interactive pop-up dialog?

Tags: interactive, popup

Is there a popup input dialogue box for Emacs, which returns the string that a user enters? Maybe something that can be launched through the mini-buffer? Or through an elisp command/function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yes-or-no-p` provides this for yes/no answers (and it's often used cousin `y-or-no-p`).

Several arguments to the [`interactive`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) macro can allow prompting for arguments when a function is called interactively (using <kbd>M-x</kbd> to call the function, binding a key to the function, or using `call-interactively`).

As mentioned in the documentation for `interactive` above, [`read-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-from-Minibuffer.html) will prompt the minibuffer for a string and return it to the caller.

Finally, [`completing-read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-Completion.html#Minibuffer-Completion) can be used to prompt the user with options for completion. For instance, `switch-to-buffer` and `find-file` use wrapper functions around `completing-read` that provide a list of current buffers or the files in the current directory as candidate completions. `completing-read` then uses that list of candidates to prompt the user on what file or buffer to open.

Comment: Just to add to @dgtized answer, there are a bunch of read-* that will help do things like completion in the minibuffer. read-file-name for example will autocomplete a path like you'd see with C-x C-f (find-file).

Comment: A minor detail: `y-or-n-p` does not use the minibuffer.  It reads an event (keypress).

Answer (score 1):

interactive has several [code characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes) which can be what you are looking for. If you write a function, you can specify that the user needs to provide a plain string, a buffer name, etc. All from the minibuffer.

If you want to provide completion look at `ido-completing-read`, from [ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/InteractivelyDoThings), to request user input anywhere in your function (and it's easy to use IMHO).